# How do I make a python 3.6 venv directory to use with IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, python-venv

I'm running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10` and IntelliJ

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-201.6668.121, built on April 8, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_251-b08 arm
VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Linux 4.19.114-v8+
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 743M
Cores: 4
Non-Bundled Plugins: PythonCore
Current Desktop: LXDE
```

I'd like to install a Python 3.6 venv. A Python 3.7 is already installed. However, when I try to do this via the normal menu-mechanism, I receive an error:
[Add SDK Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvkOb.png) 
[Setup Python SDK Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TPaE.png)
[image: IntelliJ Can't Create Python 3.6 venv Error Dialog]

I thought about making such a directory using the command line but the ones I saw besides `pyvenv` don't make a directory:

```
    Create a new project using Python 3.6, specifically:
   $ pipenv --python 3.6
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried [creating a venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) from the system terminal? Does it fail with the same error?
Make sure you use the same interpreter as a base.

Comment: it gives the same error showed in the screenshot - exact same but in a terminal [https://imgur.com/uimWX4t ]

Comment: and taking their advice regarding installing python-venv says its the newest one [https://imgur.com/PmU1iH8 ]